# Is it possible to declare a module for a file which is not in the same directory in Rust?

Tags: rust

So let's say I have a directory like so:

```
src/
  lib.rs
  foo.rs
  bar/
    baz.rs
```

In order to declare a module with the contents of `foo.rs`, I can declare a module like so in `lib.rs`

```
// lib.rs
mod foo;
```

Is there any way declare a module with the contents of `bar/baz.rs` directly inside of `lib.rs`?  I know I can achieve this by creating a `mod.rs` file inside of the `/bar` directory, but I am wondering if I can skip this somehow.

In other words, I am wondering if there is some analog to something like the `C` include statement:

```
// lib.rs
#include "bar/baz.rs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but...

- It is *highly* recommended against, unless you have a very good reason.
- You cannot name it `bar::baz`, it needs to be one identifier.

The solution is [the `#[path]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute). It allows you to declare a module with path different than the default ones.

In lib.rs:

```
#[path = "bar/baz.rs"]
mod bar_baz;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write in `lib.rs`:

```rust
mod bar {
    mod baz;
}
```

then the `mod baz` will look for a file according to its full path (`crate::bar::baz` corresponds to `src/bar/baz.rs`), not according to what file it is written in, so it will find the file you want. No `#[path]` involved, but this does mean that a `bar` module exists.